# LibVLCShrap can't not use opengl win32 video output in Avalonia application

Tags: libvlc, avaloniaui, avalonia, libvlcsharp

[ASS subtitles are all black (unreadable) with VLC 3.0.8 and newer](https://www.reddit.com/r/VLC/comments/s2ugbq/ass_subtitles_are_all_black_unreadable_with_vlc/)

This problems is also occur in LibVLCSharp. So I want to solve this problem by switching the video output to OpenGL(win32) by using advance command-line `--vout=glwin32` when new a LibVlC instance in code, such as `var _libVlc = new LibVLC("--vout=glwin32");`.

But I found that it can't switch successfully when the media player binding to a Videoview control in axmal. [With Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJhuZ.png)

When the media player playing video with no binding, it will create a new window automatically, in this case it work. [Without Binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxYm4.png)

Is there any workrounds to fix this? Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do that. The Avalonia control is implemented by using the set_hwnd function, that internally forces the use of d3d11.

If you wanted to use opengl instead, you would need libvlc4 hw-accelerated callbacks, and *a lot of* manual work...

I'd prefer to submit a bug on VLC if it does not already exist and wait for it to be fixed.